# Braintree in multi-currency

Tags: paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm trying to integrate Braintree into my website to accept payments and I have a couple of questions regarding the multi-currency support. 
First let me say that I have created an account that accepts **EUR**, since I live in the EU.

Now, let's say that an american guy wants to buy something on my webapp. He obviously has a credit card tied to a **USD** bank account. Reading the doc I found that in Braintree I **cannot** specify the currency, hence my amount, in this case `10`, is 10 EUR

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
        amount: 10,
        paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
        options: {
            submitForSettlement: true
        }
    })
```

Which means that on my website I'll have to display

```
Would you like to buy this item for 11.16 USD?
```

where 11.16 is the current conversion rate (at the time of writing).

Is this the right way to do this?? **I am skeptical** for 2 reasons:

- Say I use an online real-time converter >> if the user refreshes the page he may find a different amount (**BAD UX**)
- Say I set a fixed conversion rate, e.g. 1 EUR == 1.1 USD >> the user will find a different amount charged on his card wrt to the one displayed in the website. This is because I actually charge 10 EUR not 11 USD as advertise (**BAD UX**)

Can you please help me understand **the correct way** to handle this??

Every time I bought something from a foreign website I got the conversion displayed in EUR and I've been charged with the exact amount, but here on Braintree I don't understand how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, I recommend reaching out to our awesome [Support Team](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You specify the currency of a transaction by passing the [`merchantAccountId`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#merchant_account_id). This prevents you from having to do a ton of conversion for every transaction.

Here's a modified version of the example from [Braintree's developer docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#specify-merchant-account-id):

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: "10.00",
  merchantAccountId: "your_merchant_account",
  paymentMethodNonce: nonce_from_the_client,
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true
  }
})
```

If you haven't already and you have a production account, you should reach out to [Braintree's team](https://help.braintreepayments.com/) to request the currencies you need to process. If you're just testing in sandbox, you can create test merchant accounts by following [these steps](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/try-it-out#testing-currencies).

Comment: David, does Braintree allow EUR settlement (not just presentment) for a Singapore business?